# how to use tal statement in plone default home page?

Tags: python, plone

I created simple static website on zmi page . I need to get return value of python in plone front page. I put tal statement in front-page/edit and save it. But it not work .Then after i checked  with the same path now that tal statements not present here.
my tal code is

```
<div tal:define="address context/@@address-view" >
  <span tal:define="li address/myaddress" >
    <span tal:replace="structure python:li" />
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as i understand what you have done.

I guess you simply modified Plone's "front-page" item, which is a ATDocument. 
For security reasons you cannot execute `tal` directly in regular ContentType (TextField).

You have to create your own ZPT View in ZMI (Which handles tal fine :-))

1. Goto `http://plonesite/manage_main`
2. Add "Page Template" - name it `index_html` (delete plone's default front page). Also remove the code already placed in the fresh created page template.
3. Use the plone master macro, so your code will be places in the content or main slot.

```
<html i18n:domain="plone"
  lang="en"
  metal:use-macro="here/main_template/macros/master"
  xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"
  xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
  xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal">


 <body>
     <div metal:fill-slot="main">

           ... YOUR CODE HERE...
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

1. Save - and your done.

Comment: I you have several page templates an you want a specific one as startpage. Click on the `Property` Tab in ZMI -> Add or modify the property named "layout" and fill in the id of your page template.

Comment: my question is ,is it possible to use tal statement in html source editor which is in zmi. i mention the path http://localhost:8089/support/daten/chemical/chemical2/edit

Comment: here daten is my folder and chemical is inner folder and chemical2 is html page

Comment: There's a product for this purpose --> https://plone.org/products/scriptablefields but you have to create you own content type or patch an existing one. I'm also not sure which plone version this package supports... it's very old. IMHO never let people run python or tal expressions in a contenttype. create `index_html` ZPT's where necessary and you are done.